# Testing with jmeter Trying to login in to Wikipedia

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter.. I have successfully generated the dynamic token using regular expression but i am still not able to successfully log in. even though my tests are pass.. Please help what am I missing?

[image: Request/Response]

Comment: And what Error you are getting?

Comment: No Error at all... but I am not logged in my account and successfully generating the Token using Regular expression . In the image see Username is punched in But not the Password.

Comment: It would be rude to run a load test against Wikipedia.  If you want to load-test something, please use your own web service.

Answer (score 10):

Try to record your script with Blazemeter and run the test. See if you get same error. If not then compare the two scripts and check what went wrong with your script.

Blazemeter is an extension of Google Chrome. You can create a free account and record your script and then export the JMX file. Use this file in Jmeter to run the test.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this [Login authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication) Not sure if its gonna help in addressing your issue!

Comment: what is it? its better if you write some of it here itself